# Issue in store user details in sql database

Tags: php, sql

I have created register form page using php.

This is code_exec.php:

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    session_start();
    $form = $_POST;
    $fname=$form['fname'];
    $lname=$form['lname'];
    $email=$form['email'];
    $pass=$form['pass'];
    $phone=$form['phone'];
    $sex_select=$form['sex_select'];
    $month=$form['month'];
    $day=$form['day'];
    $year=$form['year'];

 $result = "INSERT INTO crop ( fname, lname, email, pass, phone,`sex_select`, month,day,year) VALUES 
 ( :fname, :lname, :email, :pass, :phone, :sex_select, :month, :day, :year)";
if (!$result) {
    die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
}
 ?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crop', $user, $pass );
?>
```

Now i didn't show any error, but didn't store user data.

May i know, what is my mistake with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the field "year" from your table and rename it to something else.As mysql treats the year like a keyword .so it will not allow you to insert data into the table.

The same problem was raised for me few days back. I have tested in phpmyadmin.I found this solution.

And Also you need to execute the query like this

```
mysql_query($result);
```

then check if it is not executed..

Comment: It may not be listed there.but it worked for me only when I changed the field name for year.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try like this

```
include 'config.php';
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    session_start();
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];


$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO crop (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `pass`, `phone`,`sex_select`, `month`,`day`,`year`) VALUES ( :fname, :lname, :email, :pass, :phone, :sex_select, :month, :day, :year)");
$result->bindValue(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':sex_select', $sex_select, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':month', $month, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':day', $day, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result->execute();
```

Comment: I suggest you to get variable like `$fname=$_POST['fname'];` instead of `$fname=$form['fname'];` for all the variables;

Comment: got it thanks, and i need query retrieve data from database using pdo